# PyPlot with IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, python-idle

I am attempting to plot some data using matplotlib.pyplot in IDLE. This is my first time trying to use matplotlib outside of a classroom.

My code is pretty straightforward: load some data from a CSV into a dataframe and try to put it on a scatterplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

filename = 'data.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=',')

plot_me = data.plot(x=data['Density'], y=data['Cost per Pupil'], kind='scatter')
```

However, this returns a long error which I am having trouble following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dmccarville/Desktop/DJM Figures/plot.py", line 10, in <module>
    plot_me = data.plot(x=data['Density'], y=data['Cost per Pupil'], kind='scatter')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 2617, in __call__
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 1859, in plot_frame
    **kwds)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 1684, in _plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 240, in generate
    self._make_plot()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 833, in _make_plot
    scatter = ax.scatter(data[x].values, data[y].values, c=c_values,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1958, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2002, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1168, in _convert_to_indexer
    return labels.get_loc(obj)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2442, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5280)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 134, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:4819)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 51, in __str__
    return self.__unicode__()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 982, in __unicode__
    width, height = get_terminal_size()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\terminal.py", line 33, in get_terminal_size
    return shutil.get_terminal_size()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 1071, in get_terminal_size
    size = os.get_terminal_size(sys.__stdout__.fileno())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

I was able to locate [this bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue24920), which suggests that this can't be accomplished with IDLE. As something of a novice, that sounds incredible to me.

Is this correct? Can I really not make a scatterplot using IDLE? If I can, what do I need to do?

Comment: First, simplify your program, such that it doesn't depend on external data, such that the error is reproducible. See [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a guide to debugging your problem:

First, simplify your program, such that it doesn't depend on external data, such that the error is reproducible. See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This could look like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({"x" : [1,2,3],"y":[3,2,4]})

plot_me = data.plot(x=data['x'], y=data['y'], kind='scatter')

plt.show()
```

Now running this will produce an error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Data\Computer\Entwicklung\python\SO_plot_dataframe.py", line 13, in <module>
    plot_me = data.plot(x=data['x'], y=data['y'], kind='scatter')

# and so on.
```

This indicates that there is something wrong with the creation of the plot, not the actual showing.

To see what could go wrong, (1) look at other examples and/or (2) [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html). From the documentation you will find that the arguments `x` and `y` should be a "label or position", but not a dataframe column itself.

So changing

```
plot_me = data.plot(x=data['x'], y=data['y'], kind='scatter')
```

to

```
plot_me = data.plot(x='x', y='y', kind='scatter')
```

where `x` and `y` are column labels from the DataFrame, will give you the desired plot.

At the end this has nothing to do with IDLE, but with a wrong syntax used in one of the commands.

Answer (score 0):

About the IDLE part of the question: if you start IDLE from a command line console (Command Prompt or PowerShell on Windows) with `python -m idlelib` (or `py -3.4 -m idlelib`), then `sys.__stdout__` will be the console and the `.fileno()` call will succeed and return 1 and the `os.get_terminal_size(1)` call will return the size of the console window.  Pyplot should then print to either the console or the IDLE shell (I do not know which).